# Search option index via option text

Tags: javascript, html

Hi is there anyway to return the index of an option by it's text? (without jquery or any lib)

```
<select>
     <option>I</option> //0
     <option>Love</option> //1
     <option>my</option> //2
     <option>granny<option> //3
</select>
```

say for example I'll pass a string "granny" it'll return 3

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean (a) a function that you will send "granny" to, and it will look through the options and return 3 for you, or (b) when the user selects "granny" on the front-end you want to know that it was number 3 that was selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being inactive for few days, here's the one I made, It'll return the index of an option based on the needed string, not the value. I just thought there's an easy function to do the process but I think there's none. just in case, this will do.

HTML

```
<select id = "myDropDown">
     <option>I</option> //0
     <option>Love</option> //1
     <option>my</option> //2
     <option>granny<option> //3
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var dropDownList = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
var str = "granny";
var i =0;
for(i=0;i<dropDownList.length;i++){
    if(dropDownList.options[i].text == str){
        console.log("index: " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a select element that looks like this:

```
<select id="ddlViewBy">
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Running this code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: If you copy your answer from somewhere you must give the reference atleast.. Original answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/2260614

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but what if I would not select "granny" option on the drop down list? + not by value, but by it's text or innerHTML.. anyway, I already answered my own question via loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
 <option value="0">I</option> //0
 <option value="1">Love</option> //1
 <option value="2">my</option> //2
 <option value="3">granny<option> //3
</select>
```

Comment: thanks anyway, I already solved it using loops and conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the index
***[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/3XGz8/)***
*Javascript code*

```
function findIndex() {
    var e = document.getElementById("select1");
    alert(e.selectedIndex);
}
```

*HTML*

```
<select id="select1" onchange="findIndex()">
    <option>I</option>
    <option>Love</option>
    <option>my</option>
    <option>granny</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to retrieve the selected Index on change event of Select so you can try the following Code.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4YUU/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="select1">
     <option>I</option> 
     <option>Love</option>
     <option>my</option> 
    <option>granny</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var select1=document.getElementById("select1");
select1.onchange=function(){
var s=document.getElementById("select1").selectedIndex;
alert(s);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

yes and example here from w3chools

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp